# Coordinates of point on cubic bezier in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bezier

I'm trying to create a JS function that will return a Y coordinate on a cubic bezier given the X coordinate. Here's what I have:

```
function pointOnBezier(t, p0, p1, p2, p3) {
   var x = Math.pow(1-t,3) * p0[0] + 3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * p1[0] + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * p2[0] + t * t * t * p3[0];
   var y = Math.pow(1-t,3) * p0[1] + 3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * p1[1] + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * p2[1] + t * t * t * p3[1];
  return [x, y];
}

console.log(0.25, pointOnBezier(0.25, [0,0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0]));
console.log(0.5, pointOnBezier(0.5, [0,0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0]));
console.log(0.75, pointOnBezier(0.75, [0,0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0]));
```

I included the three test values. If you run the code, the expected results of t=0.25 and t=0.75 is a value of 0.25 and 0.75 but it's returning 0.3 and 0.7.

Can anyone see the problem with the calculations?

Edit: while similar to other questions, I've looked at the answers there and so far I haven't found a working solution plus the discussion has continued about the merits of two common techniques.

Comment: This is covered over on https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx

Answer (score 0):

There are three values involved in such Bezier curves: `t` which is the input to the function, and `x` and `y` which are the output.
Your code returns the value of `x` and `y` for a given value of `t`, but there is no reason `t` would be related to `x` in any obvious way.

Generally speaking it is easy to get `x` and `y` from `t` (your code), but it is more complicated to get `y` from `x`. <s>The only</s> One way to do it is by binary search: try some values of `t` until you get close enough to the desired `x`, which also gets you the `y` you are looking for.

Example code (untested and assuming the bezier curve is increasing):

```js
const EPSILON = 0.00001;
const getY = (x, p0, p1, p2, p3) => {
    let minT = 0;
    let maxT = 1;
    while (maxT - minT > EPSILON) {
        const t = (minT + maxT) / 2;
        const newX = pointOnBezier(t, p0, p1, p2, p3)[0];
        if (newX > x) {
            maxT = t;
        } else {
            minT = t;
        } 
    }
    return pointOnBezier(minT, p0, p1, p2, p3)[1];
};
```

*Edit:*
As mentioned in the comments, another way to do it without binary search would be to solve the third degree equation mathematically to directly get the correct value of `t`, and then calculate the corresponding `y`. However this would most likely lead to significantly more complicated code, for no clear benefit.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. I think my wording confused matters a little. I'm trying to return a Y position based on X but in this case X and 't' are sort of the same being that I'm trying to retrive a Y value based on a position in the X axis and the X axis can be seen at "time" or t? Or maybe I'm getting a  bit mixed up.

Comment: Even though you have (I assume) Bezier curves where `x` goes from 0 to 1, it does not mean that `x` and `t` are the same. Yes, both are increasing, start at 0, and go to 1, but they do so at different and varying speeds (depending on the control points of the curve), which is why you are getting 0.3 instead of 0.25. `t` and `x` are two different, unrelated values.

Comment: Ah interesting stuff Guillaume, thank you. So what I'm trying to do is way more tricky than I first thought?

Comment: Yes, it is more tricky than it seems, because Bezier curves are naturally parameterized by `t`, not by `x`. Note also that depending on how you put the handles, you could end up with several possible values of `y` for the same `x`, or none at all, so it can't just be a simple formula.

Comment: But is is possible to get X and Y values using t to index the curve?

Comment: Yes, the code in my answer gives the `y` corresponding to a given `x` (making some assumptions on the Bezier curve, for instance that `x` does increase with `t` and that the argument `x` is between the minimum and the maximum).

Comment: Important math note: for cubic curves you can _most certainly_ find `t` given `x`. It's a third order polynomial, we can find the roots for that just fine using Cardano's method. We don't need binary searching. See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx, with https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extremities covering Cardano's algorithm.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Thanks Mike, that's an amazing resouce you've created there!

That curve with the X slider is exactly the results I need but I'm afraid my math is far too basic to be able to translate that into code. In the code in the "Y For X" section it's referring to functions that I can't see on the page. Is there anywhere I can see the whole code for that?

Comment: which ones? Because the code for Cardano's algorithm is on the page (second link), written in JS already.

Comment: While having an exact formula is mathematically nice. I don't think that it really makes sense in this context. It will simply lead to significantly more complicated code, less generalizable, and with potentially more issues like rounding errors when dividing by numbers close to zero.

Comment: I don't disagree, LUTs are fast and often accurate enough, but "The only way to do it is by binary search" is simply not true and could do with an edot.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited my answer.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie
I tried implementing the binary search in your post (had to modify to suit my needs). It works for a linear curve where the control points are at 0.5 but produces the same results regardless of the control points positions. Here's how I implemented it:

Comment: `this.bezierYAtX = function(x, p0, p1, p2, p3) {
    var precision = 0.001;
    var minT = 0.0;
    var maxT = 1.0;
    while (maxT - minT > precision) {
      var t = (minT + maxT) / 2.0;
      var newX = this.cubicBezierPoint(t, p0, p1, p2, p3).x;
      if (newX > x) {
        maxT = t;
      } else {
        minT = t;
      }
    }
    return this.cubicBezierPoint(minT, p0, p1, p2, p3).y;
  }`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure how to make it tidier.